# I want to show Html message in my AlertBox in xamarin form How Can I do

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

This Below is Dialog Service

```
public async Task<bool> ShowConfirmAsync(string message, string title, string positivebuttonLabel, string negativebuttonLabel)
        {
            var result = await UserDialogs.Instance.ConfirmAsync(new ConfirmConfig
            {
                Message = message,
                OkText = positivebuttonLabel,
                CancelText = negativebuttonLabel
            });
            return result;
        }
```

The Below Is My Html Data

```
"affect (n.) aspect of an emotion (mostly used in psychology)<BR>effect (n.) change, event, condition<BR>affect (v.) produce an effect; influence; afflict<BR>effect (v.) cause or bring about<BR>Ex: She will effect changes that will affect everyone."
```

I have use for display this message

```
var data = info as OccurrencesInfo;
            if (data != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(data.Info))
            {              
                var InfoData= data.Info;
                await DialogService.ShowAlertAsync(InfoData, AppResources.InfoTitle, AppResources.FlagOk);
            }
```

When I am use this logic it show as it is with contain html tag .But I want to show this dialog apply all html tag on my dialog message. How can I do

Comment: Are you using aritchie/userdialogs ? HTML support from PR465 was never committed, plus that project is not active any more

Comment: No Sir I am not using this Aritchie/userdialog. I am just using our inbuld xamarin form dialog " using Acr.UserDialogs;"

Comment: Acr.UserDialogs (nuget name) IS aritchie/userdialogs (github repo) and it does not support HTML, look at the source and the PRs: https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs and it is a non-active project, see the repo readme, so you can clone the repo and do a pull/merge with PR 465 and try that....

Answer (score 0):

Why not formatting your message that way instead of using HTML :

replace `<BR>` with  `\n`

```
"affect (n.) aspect of an emotion (mostly used in psychology) \n effect (n.) change, event, condition \n affect (v.) produce an effect; influence; afflict \n effect (v.) cause or bring about \n Ex: She will effect changes that will affect everyone."
```

Comment: Actually "data.Info" its a response filed from API ,How can I change this

Comment: use the replace method like this : yourString.Replace("<BR>" , \n");

Comment: Ok I Agree with this, but some time the response is this format that's why I want to show html data with applied format  "ensure (v.)<BR><su>makes sure</su>, <su>secures</su>, <su>establishes</su>, <su>safeguards</su>"

Comment: ensures
Synonyms (help to avoid repetition and add flavor)
ensure (v.)
makes sure, secures, establishes, safeguards

Source: Synonyms

Answer (score 0):

Since `aritchie/userdialogs` is is not active any more , I suggest you use [rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup) .

You can create a a new PopupPage , and place a label(Html type) inside it to show the html data .

Check details here : https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup/wiki/PopupPage.